# Compute a cardinality using Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory

I posted the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656077/compute-a-cardinality-using-chinese-remainder-theorem) but I got no response.

I am looking for computing this cardinality:
$$N(q)=\#\Bigg\{n \in \mathbb{N} \ | \ \gcd\bigg(n^2+1, \prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ p\text{ prime}}}p\bigg)=1 , \ \ n^2+1 \leqslant \!\!\!\prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ p\text{ prime}}}\!\!p \Bigg\},$$
by using **Chinese remainder theorem**.

First, for $p$ odd prime and $m\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, the number of solutions of the equation $m^2 + 1 = 0 \pmod p$ is :
$$
\begin{cases} 
0 & \text{ if } p = 3 \pmod 4 \\ 
2 & \text{ if } p = 1 \pmod 4 
\end{cases}.$$

Using the **Chinese remainder theorem** and the **fundamental counting principle**, I get this result:
$$N(q) = \bigg(\prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ p \equiv 3[4] \\ p\text{ prime}}}p \bigg)\prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ p \equiv 1[4] \\ p\text{ prime}}}(p-2) \label{1}\tag{1}$$
Formula \eqref{1} seems not correct as when I check $N(q)$ numerically I do not get the same results as by counting.

The true values are :
$$N(7)=5, \ N(11)=15, \ N(13)=45 , \ N(17)=161, \ N(19)=698, \cdots$$

**Question:** Why my formula \eqref{1} is not correct !? And what is the correct formula ?

Many thanks for any help.

Numerically it's very likely that:
$$N(q) \approx \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\displaystyle \prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ p\text{ prime}}}p }} \, \bigg(\prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ p \equiv 3[4] \\ p\text{ prime}}}p \bigg)\prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ p \equiv 1[4] \\ p\text{ prime}}}(p-2)$$

Comment: You can see yourself looking already at $q = 3$, say, that your solution overcounts:  it allows all residue classes modulo $p$, but your condition $n^2 + 1 \le \prod p$ allows only some.  For example, the only allowable $n$ when $q = 3$ are $n = 0$ and $n = 2$; since $n = 4$ is too big, we already get $N(3) = 2$, not $N(3) = \prod_{\substack{p \le 3 \\ p \equiv 3 \pmod4}} p = 3$ as predicted.

Comment: First of all, you forgot $p=2$, secondly you Chinese remainders method works prexisely only for $n\leq \prod p$ but you need thoose $n$ with $n^2+1\leq \prod p$

Comment: @LSpice, we have $N(3)=2$, since the only numbers coprime to $6$ and less than $6$ are $1,5$ and both are written as $n^2+1$. As i say formula $(1)$ not correct.

Comment: @PavelKozlov, thank you, i check and you you have right.

Comment: It sounds like you [disagree](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359217/compute-a-cardinality-using-chinese-remainder-theorem#comment904156_359217), but actually I think we ([and](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359217/compute-a-cardinality-using-chinese-remainder-theorem#comment904114_359217) @PavelKozlov) [agree](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359217/compute-a-cardinality-using-chinese-remainder-theorem#comment904113_359217).

Comment: @PavelKozlov, I think the error is only in not taking into account the requirement that $n^2 + 1 \le \prod p$, not in leaving out $p = 2$; indeed, because $n^2 + 1$ has to be coprime to $\prod p$, hence in particular to $2$, we're restricted to $n \equiv 0 \pmod2$.

Comment: The correct formula is : $$\displaystyle\#\Bigg\{n \in \mathbb{N} \ | \ \gcd\bigg(n^2+1, \prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ p\text{ prime}}}p\bigg)=1 , \ \ n \leqslant \!\!\!\prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ p\text{ prime}}}\!\!p \Bigg\} = \displaystyle\bigg(\prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ p \equiv 3[4] \\ p\text{ prime}}}p \bigg)\prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ p \equiv 1[4] \\ p\text{ prime}}}(p-2)$$

Comment: Is there a factor $e^{-\gamma}$ to pay attention to?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN yes, see my article : [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02620310)